# Set up class properties in a loop

Tags: php, class, loops, properties

I have a php class like this

```
class data{

    var $counter;
    var $a;
    var $b;
    var $c;
    var $d;
    var $e;
    var $f;
    var $g;
    var $h;
    var $etc;

    function data(){$this->counter=0;}

    function addvalue($value){
        $this->a[$this->counter]=$value;
        $this->b[$this->counter]=0;
        $this->c[$this->counter]=0;
        $this->d[$this->counter]=0;
        $this->e[$this->counter]=0;
        $this->f[$this->counter]=0;
        $this->g[$this->counter]=0;
        $this->h[$this->counter]=0;
        $this->etc[$this->counter]=0;
        $this->counter++;
    }

}
```

Then, an object of that class

```
if(isset($_SESSION['data'])==0){
    $_SESSION['data']=new data();
}
```

The code works, but I'm curious about if I could setting up all those properties with the same value: "0", in a foreach loop. I tried this approach with no success:

```
function addvalue($value){

    foreach($this as $key => $value){
        if($key!='counter'){$this->$key[$this->counter]=0;}
    }

    $this->a[$this->counter]=$value;
    $this->counter++;

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe because you have two `$value` in `addvalue`. The one in function parameters and the one in `foreach`

Comment: Also, what's your problem exactly?

Comment: Hi. The two $value could be a problem or not. Hard to say because that was just an example. It's different in my code, which also works perfectly. I was just trying to optimizing it, to getting rid off of some lines of code, using a loop iteration instead. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the `{$this->$key[$this->counter]=0;}` statement wrong. It should be

```
if( $key != 'counter' ) {
    $this->{$key}[$this->counter] = 0;
}
```

(notice the braces surrounding `$key`).

A more complex dynamic expression of a variable name requires braces syntax.

Comment: Those curly braces surrounding the variable $key made all the difference and accomplished the goal perfectly. You rock!

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do this:-

```
class data{

    var $counter = 0;
    var $a = 0;
    var $b = 0;
    var $c = 0;
    var $d = 0;
    var $e = 0;
    var $f = 0;
    var $g = 0;
    var $h = 0;
    var $etc = 0;

}
```

To assign default values. If that is what you are trying to achieve, I'm not 100% sure.

I think that I should point out that PHP now uses `__construct()` as the constructor name, not a method with the same name as the class.

Comment: Thank you. I will replace the constructor name, although it works fine using the class name, but it's a best practice, because in a new php version it could be deprecated. I wasn't trying to assign default values, rather initial values. But as an array. That's why it can't be: var $etc=0, instead, within the method: $etc[n]=0.